# Bash shell script passing a variable onto curly braces

Tags: linux, bash, shell, posix

I am pulling my hair out,

```
#!/bin/sh
queryNumber=10

if [ "$1" == "start" ]; then
        systemctl start myProcess@{1..$queryNumber}
elif [ "$1" == "stop" ]; then
        systemctl stop myProcess@*
fi
```

Does anybody knows why I am not being able to pass the `$queryNumber` parameter onto the shell script

Comment: What command do you want to be executed? `systemctl start myProcess@1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9` or `systemctl start myProcess@1 myProcess@2...`

Comment: What I would like is to start a N amount of processes based on a variable @Mathieu but it seems like it enters on a confusion when I execute the script, it seems like bash can't read properly the ``$queryNumber`` variable

Comment: Brace expansion occurs *before* parameter expansion, so this is a well known "can't do that" in `bash`. Use a loop to define an array instead.

Comment: BTW, if you want compatibility with `sh`, use `=` not `==` in your `[` commands. See [the POSIX specification for `test`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) for the list of guaranteed portable operators.

Comment: `echo {1..$queryNumber}` correctly writes `{1..10}`; the problem is not that bash can't "pass the variable into curly braces", the problem is that brace expansion does not work the way you think it does.

Comment: (Or, just call `systemctl start` multiple times in a loop, if you want to keep POSIX compatibility instead of using `bash`.)

Comment: One could overwrite `$@` (optionally inside a function) to do this while keeping POSIX compatibility and calling `systemctl start` only once.

Comment: Note that although "eval is evil", you may simply want `eval "systemctl ... {1..$queryNumber}"`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Excellent suggestion.  And timely enough that I could still edit the comment.

Comment: To demonstrate the overwrite-`$@` approach briefly: `set --; for ((i=0; i<queryNumber; i++)); do set -- "$@" "myProcess@$i"; done; systemctl start "$@"`. Note that the `for var in ((expr1; expr2; expr3))` loop form there is a bashism; if you wanted a POSIXy version, it would be like `i=-1; set --; while i=$((i + 1)); [ "$i" -lt "$queryNumber" ]; do set -- "$@" "myProcess@$i"; done; systemctl start "$@"`

Comment: Also, you should quote `myProcess@*`, as in, `systemctl stop 'myProcess@*'` -- otherwise it won't work if you run it in a directory that has a `myProcess@.service` file, or any other filename that starts with `myProcess@`.

Comment: Hi @CharlesDuffy many thanks for the answers, could you please, link me any helpful advanced book for learning bash and posix? Thanks.

Comment: I recommend the Wooledge [BashGuide](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide). The same wiki it's hosted on has several other useful resources -- among them, the [BashFAQ](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ) and the [BashPitfalls](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls) page. Also good is the [bash-hackers' wiki](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/). I strongly recommend you _avoid_ the ABS ("Advanced" Bash Scripting guide) and anything else from TLDP.

Comment: Incidentally, the resource I checked to find the POSIX-compliant equivalent to `for var in ((expr1; expr2; expr3))` was [the database for `greybot`](https://wooledge.org/~greybot/meta/), the #bash IRC channel factoid bot (that particular hint is in that database under the name "counting"). Lurking in that IRC channel over the course of some years in the early 2000s is how I personally learned bash.

Answer (score -2):

This may be due to queryNumber is defined as Environment Variable
or try running the program in Bash Shell rather than sh

Comment: This doesn't work even when the shell is known to be bash. It's [BashPitfalls #33](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.7B1...24n.7D).

Comment: (also, `queryNumber` is in the OP's example a regular shell variable, _not_ an environment variable -- but since all environment variables named with valid shell variable names automatically have shell variables created for them, it would be the same either way).